# Solr - edgengram and dashes in data

Tags: solr

I have a schema where I would like two fields to be `edgengram`, in order to perform "starts-with"-searches.

The data in one of the fields holds only numbers, and works (querying for `2` gives only the ones that start with `2`). The other field on the other hand, does not work that well.

This field holds data of the type `FLB-PRO`, `FLB-GJE`, `NKF-KFE`, etc. When I search this field for `FLB-PRO` for instance, I also get hits on `FLB-GJE`, which is really not what I expect when doing a "starts-with"-search. Searching for `PRO` gives me closer to what I want, only `FLB-PRO` is included in the result.

Since these two fields use the same type, I assume it has something to do with the dashes in the data, but I'm pretty blank when it comes to how to avoid this problem..

My edgengram field definition:

```
<!-- Similar to text_general, but does edgengram filtering (~"startswith") -->
<fieldType name="text_general_edgengram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="40"/>

    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Edit: Some more tinkering, at it seems that the dash in the query is treated like a whitespace when querying. I have tried escaping the `-` in my query, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to change tokenizer, the `StandardTokenizer` treats dashes as whitespace, so queries containing two letter sequences seperatet by a dash will be treated as two words.

Fixed by changing `tokenizer class` for both `query` and `index` to `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory`. This will treat the entire string as one word, regardless of dashes.